# APT error in eclipse as JSR250: CommonAnnotations for Java

Tags: eclipse

i am getting below APT error in eclipse as JSR250: CommonAnnotations for Java, 2.3: @Resource methods must be setters that follow the standard JavaBeans convention. i.e. void "setProperty( value)" for " property".

Firstly I got the same 256 errors, I created a new workspace and imported maven projects again into new workspace then they reduced to 9 errors.

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are referring multiple repositories in you project. Please check your project .factorypath file. What it is referring ?